# SQL find nearest date without going over, or return the oldest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in SQL Server with prices of items over time.  My users will be passing a date variable and I want to return the closest record without going over, or if no such record exists return the oldest record present.  For example, with the data below, if the user passes April for item A it will return the March record and for item B it will return the June record.

I've tried a lot of variations with Union All and Order by but keep getting a variety of errors.  Is there a way to write this using a Case Statement?

example:

```
case when min(Month)>Input Date then min(Month) 
else max(Month) where Month <= Input Date?
```

Sincere apologies for attaching sample dataset as an image, I couldn't get it to format right otherwise.
[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqyIl.jpg)

Comment: Use this http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to create a nice table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean going over... because in your sample you choose the `MIN(Month)` but your else choose the `MAX(month)`

Comment: I'm looking for the max(month) <= user input month, or if all month records are > user input month then return min(month).  Its confusing to write.  I have figured out the max(month)<= user input month, but am dropping the records that don't have a record <= the user input month.  However there is value for them to see the record closest to their input, even if it's > user input month.

Comment: Can you post the table as text using the site I provide you?

Comment: Sadly, I still haven't resolved.  I'm going down the path of creating a temporary table with item and date then selecting the MIN(Date) and re-joining back to original table to get price.  My code thus far:(SELECT
[Commodity Code],
min([Date]) as [Date]
   
FROM    Reporting.commodity_weekly_v
WHERE   [Date] > '2016-02-06'

group by
[Commodity Code]

                
UNION ALL
      
SELECT
[Commodity Code],
max([Date]) as [Date]

FROM    Reporting.commodity_weekly_v
where [Date] <= '2016-02-06'

group by
[Commodity Code])
order by [Commodity Code], [Date]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT TOP (1) with order by DATE DESC + Item type + date comparison to get the latest. ORDER BY will order records by date, then you get the latest either this month (if exists) or earlier months.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline of a query (without more of your table it's hard to be exact):

```
  WITH CTE AS
  (
  SELECT
    ITEM,
    PRICE,
    MIN(ACTUAL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY ITEM) AS MIN_DATE,
    MAX(INPUT_DATE<=ACTUAL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY ITEM,ACTUAL_DATE) AS MATCHED_DATE
  FROM TABLE
  )
SELECT
  CTE.ITEM,
  CTE.PRICE,
  CASE 
    WHEN
      CTE.MATCHED_DATE IS NOT NULL
    THEN 
      CTE.MATCHED_DATE
    ELSE
      CTE.MIN_DATE
    END AS MOSTLY_MATCHED_DATE
FROM CTE
GROUP BY 
  CTE.ITEM, 
  CTE.PRICE
```

The idea is that in a Common Table Expression, you use the `PARTITION BY` function to identify the key date for each item, record by record, and then you do a test in aggregate to pull either your matched record or your default record.